# Parse tweepy response

Tags: python, data-structures, tweepy

I'm searching for tweets of blockchain using tweepy, for that I'm using the following code:

Auth:

```
consumerKey = ""
consumerSecret = ""
accessToken = ""
accessTokenSecret = ""

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumerKey, consumerSecret)
auth.set_access_token(accessToken, accessTokenSecret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
```

Search:

```
query = 'blockchain'
max_tweets = 5
searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query).items(max_tweets)]
```

But I'm not clear on how to parse the data from here, the variable `searched_tweets` is a list with only one element:

```
print type(searched_tweets)
print len(searched_tweets)

<type 'list'>
5
```

First element from there is a `tweepy.models.Status` which a don't get how to parse.

```
"Status(contributors=None, truncated=False, text=u'RT @AdEx_Network: A shoutout to Richard Kastelein for mentioning the AdEx crowdsale #ico #tokensale #ad\u2026', is_quote_status=False, in_reply_to_status_id=None, id=884958221147938816L, favorite_count=0, _api=<tweepy.api.API object at 0xb25ec08c>, author=User(follow_request_sent=False, has_extended_profile=False, profile_use_background_image=True, _json={u'follow_request_sent': False, u'has_extended_profile': False, u'profile_use_background_image': True, u'default_profile_image': False, u'id': 846284378112090112L, u'profile_background_image_url_https': None, u'verified': False, u'translator_type': u'none', u'profile_text_color': u'333333', u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/873212431106834432/-QdMHr0M_normal.jpg', u'profile_sidebar_fill_color': u'DDEEF6', u'entities': {u'description': {u'urls': []}}, u'followers_count': 735, u'profile_sidebar_border_color': u'C0DEED', u'id_str': u'846284378112090112', u'profile_background_color': u'F5F8FA', u'listed_count': 0, u'is_translation_enabled': False, u'utc_offset': None, u'statuses_count': 100, u'description': u'', u'friends_count': 126, u'location': u'', u'profile_link_color': u'1DA1F2', u'profile_image_url': u'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/873212431106834432/-QdMHr0M_normal.jpg', u'following': False, u'geo_enabled': False, u'profile_background_image_url': None, u'screen_name': u'AfiniChristy', u'lang': u'id', u'profile_background_tile': False, u'favourites_count': 100, u'name': u'Fitri Christy Afini', u'notifications'"
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the text from the Status object you have two options. First is to simply use `.text` and get the text of the tweets in the list, so, for example:

```
>>> searched_tweets[0].text
'RT @LiquidHub: The World Of #Cryptocurrency\n\n#Blockchain #Fintech #makeyourownlane #Mpgvip #AI #defstar5 #IOT #Bitcoin #GrowthHacking #Bigd…'
```

Notice this is truncating with "..." at the end of the tweet, per the docs this is because they are actually retweets, to get a full text from a Status object you should change your request and then use `.full_text`:

```
searched_tweets = [status for status in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=query, tweet_mode='extended').items(max_tweets)]

# Then you can print the full text tweets:
>>> searched_tweets[4].full_text
'RT @StakepoolCom: Crypto Percentages Up Over 100% Today Check it out! #cryptocurrency #steem #blockchain'
```